# Quizzes in Shopify

Tags: shopify

I'm trying to add a quizzes page in my checkout flow, after the customer buys a product, he/she will be presented with a Quiz Page to earn gift cards or product discounts.

So far, I've tried these apps:

- Visual Quiz Builder (https://apps.shopify.com/product-recommendation-quiz/) (Shopify app store)
- Opinion Stage (https://www.opinionstage.com/)
- Interact (https://www.tryinteract.com/)

All of these share similar functionality (creating questions and answers, and showing a final score), but only offer predefined themes in their free plans.

When I want to change the CSS to match the style of my page, I'm encouraged to buy a membership plan, and it's quite expensive given that I only need to change the CSS and this site is for a very small business.

This is the quiz page that I'm trying to achieve.

[image: Quiz mockup]

Are there any other options to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you are planning to do this after the checkout process, you can redirect to a custom page on the Thank you page and code it the way you like. If you plan to make this in the checkout flow it will require JS logic that will hide a specific until you complete the Quiz and you will need Plus store account for this!

Comment: @drip thank you for your response. In the end, that is the approach I had to follow, it is a little cumbersome since there are already apps that can help manage quizzes.